# Matlab `openvar` accepts transpose -- SOMETIMES (?!?)

Tags: matlab

Why does Matlab's `openvar` sometimes reject the use of transpose?

```
x = { 'alpha' 'bravo'}
a.x = { 'alpha' 'bravo'}

openvar('x''')
% Error:
% The first argument to VariableEditor must be a valid variable name.

openvar('a.x''')
% Works

openvar('x.''')
% Works
```

I'm using R2015b.

Comment: The input to the function must be the name of a variable, not an expression. Maybe some of these work, but by coincidence, I guess...

Comment: That's quite a coincidence.  A fortunate one, for some circumstances.

Comment: Do note that `'` is not the transpose, it is the complex conjugate transpose. `.'` is the transpose. You can type `edit openvar` to see how it is implemented (I seem to remember this one is an M-file, but I might be wrong). It is probably doing some `evalin` to evaluate the string passed. It could be instructive the learn what happens to that one quote in the first case that doesn't happen in the second or third cases. Maybe it finds the `.` in the string, and determine it needs to be processed differently?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt to dig into the code. It turns out that class `VariableEditor` has a method `checkVariableName` that checks for the expression left of a dot or bracket. For `x.'`, this is `x`, which is a good variable name. In the absence of dot or bracket, it checks the whole expression, which is `x'`, and which isn't a good variable name. At the tactical level, i see how the error arises, but the higher level reasoning is not obvious -- especially if `openvar` can evaluate and present the transpose, as the original post shows

Comment: Maybe they restricted it to variable names only because they can't support all expressions. And maybe they just haven't bothered to trap all possible non-variable-name expressions. In any case, it is very useful because there are many cases where I want a row vector, but I want to view it as a column.

Comment: Now that I'm at a MATLAB terminal, I see what you mean. The `checkVariableName` method is simply incorrect. For example, `openvar('cos(pi)')` passes the test, but the variable editor window opens up and says "*The variable cos(pi) does not exist.*" It is indeed strange that `x.'` works...

Comment: And it looks like the variable editor itself (I can't look into its code?) does a similar check. I removed the call to `checkVariableName` in `openvar`. Now `openvar('x''')` opens the editor window and says "*The variable x' does not exist.*". Likewise for `x+y`. But `x.*y` is shown!

Comment: Note that `com.mathworks.mlservices.MLArrayEditorServices.openVariable('x')` has the exact same effect as above. I guess all of this is happening in Java code. I guess the Java components don't come with sources, I don't think we'll find out what they're doing in there.

Comment: Do you want to summarize the answer, or shall I?  BTW, I found myself to `checkVariableName` from the error message, which displayed the full path. However `dbstop in matlab.desktop.vareditor.VariableEditor.checkVariableName` didn't actually cause a stop in the `checkVariableName` for those cases that were accepted by `openvar`. Instead, I recreated the error, went one level up in the call stack, and set a breakpoint at the invocation of `checkVariableName`. Seems a roundabout way to do things, and wondering why it is necessary?

Comment: Strange! I simply used the editor’s right-click menu to open `checkVariableName`. Feel free to write an answer!

Comment: I'm assuming that you have the calling function open in the editor, and you right-click the called function `checkVariableName` to open it in the editor.  But I typically banish the editor window because I use vim.  After planning my next debugging step (which is to evaluate `x.'` instead of `x'`) I then want to `dbstop in checkVariableName`, but since it is a class method, I used the full path in the error message.  That's what doesn't work, and I had to find my way to it again by re-issuing `dbstop if error` and re-evaluating `x'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tactical reasons for the acceptance of `openvar('x.''')` and
rejection of `openvar('x''')` can be seen by using `dbstop if error`.
Issuing `openvar('x''')` then shows that the error is due to class
`VariableEditor`'s method, `checkVariableName`. It checks `openvar`'s
string argument by looking to the left of any dot or bracket/brace.
For an argument `x.'`, this is `x` -- the code accepts this as a good
variable name. In the absence of dot or bracket, it checks the whole
expression, which is `x'`, and which the code doesn't recognize as a
good variable name.

While this shows how the code gives rise to the behaviour described in
the original post, the higher level reasoning is not obvious --
especially if `openvar` can evaluate and present the transpose, as the
original post shows.  Maybe TMW restricted the argument to to variable names only because it
would be too complicated to support all expressions. And maybe they
just haven't bothered to trap all possible non-variable-name
expressions. Cris Luengo noted that `openvar('cos(pi)')` passes the
test, but the variable editor window opens up and says "The variable
cos(pi) does not exist."

In any case, knowing how to tranpose data for display is very useful
because there are many cases where (i) I want/have a row vector, but
(ii) I want to view it as a column.

The reason for item (i) seems to be historical and practical. Issuing
`clear x; x(3)=7` defaults to a *row* array, i.e., spread along the
*second* dimension rather than the first dimension (downward).  This
is practical because it allows the command window to show lots of info
without scrolling too much, thus preserving much of the preceding info
for viewing (this is harking back to times before the Variable Editor) .
Furthermore, vectors need to be horizontal for the items to be iterated
over in the idiom `for myIterator = VectorOfItems`, making it
the "go-to" orientation.

The reason for item (ii) is again practical. Spreading something out
horizontally in the Variable Editor makes it hard to see, as the
default horizontal spacing is too wide.  You don't see a whole lot for
the width avaialable, and it's cognitively hard to make sense of an
array of data when it's overly spaced out like that.  Viewing such
data as a column vectors makes more sense, and the historical
considerations behind item (i) don't apply, since it is not in the
context of a scrolling command window.  As well, in the Variable
Editor, we can horizontally tile up windows for different invocations of
`openvar`, so displaying column data doesn't waste space as it would
in a scrolling command window.

**Aside:** This exercise of sleuthing into the `openvar` code revealed
oddities in specifying functions for `dbstop`.  For example, if you
specify the full path to `checkVariableName` from the error message,
no breakpoint is set. You have to issue `dbstop if error`, then submit
an unacceptable argument to `openvar` in order to cause an error,
which opens the `checkVariableName` code in the editor. Only then can
you set a breakpoint in checkVariableName using the GUI editor, or go
up one level in the stack and set a breakpoint where
`checkVariableName` is invoked.